# Installing NuGet package with EF6 Entities while running TFS causing write errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm running into a super annoying scenario and i'm hoping someone else has experienced this before and maybe has a solution or better process to follow to avoid this.

I have a custom Nuget package that uses EF6 and obviously has entity related files. When installed it loads these entities in a "Entities" folder from the root of the project.

I'm also working with TFS which is causing me all this trouble.

When i go to upgrade the package it first attempts to clear everything out by deleting the existing Entities folder so that i can then reload the new entities from the new version of the NuGet poackage. This causes the folder to go into a checkout out state for TFS. When the NuGet attempts to load the new entities it complains that:

> 1 error encountered attempting to perform the add operation on 1 item. The item $/******* cannot be changed. A parent of this item has pending delete which must be checked in first.

This is super annoying. Basically the process i have to follow to avoid this it to first delete all the entity file installed by the package, checkin the deletions and the run the update on the package which then reloads all the entity files.

Does anyone have a better solution to working with Nugets like that under source control?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have a better solution to working with Nugets like that
>   under source control?

This is a known issue related to TFS, but without a final solution. You can refer to the [Issue 4037](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4037) for detail.

> I think the TFS client logic is the issue. it should be changed so that any child add or edit with a pending parent delete causes the parent delete to be undone BUT all other children of that parent to switch to an individual delete (i.e. change from a global parent delete to a wildcard child delete except the files which were modified after the folder delete).

After tried a number of different methods I found a workaround to the problem:

Packed all the Dlls in a separate NuGet package without any content. Packed any other files into a separate package. Tagged both packages propriately so that users can find both packages easily and in relation to each other.

You can also create a dependency in the Dll package to the Content package (if you wish) so that installing the Dll package would automatically trigger installing the content package.